# How to call helper of other module in magento 2?

Tags: magento2.2

```
class ClassName {
protected $_objectManager;
function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager
) {
    $this->_objectManager     = $objectmanager;
}

public function callHelper(){
    $helperIdArr = array('Other Module Helper');
    foreach($helperIdArr as $helperId){
         $dataHelper = $this->_objectManager->get("$helperId\Helper\Data");
    }
    return $dataHelper;
}
}
```

I want to call my other custom module helper in this function.

This is working fine, but use of Object manager is not a good practice so what should i do to call my other helper.

Comment: You want to extend other call  helper's functions  or  just want to call public function?

Comment: just want to call functions of helpers

Comment: if you inject the class at `__construct` function then only can access  public.

Comment: is there any helper factory which loads all helpers in constructor ?

Comment: `all helpers` means particular one helper class all functions or all Magento helper classes?

Comment: i want to say is there something like this i can use : $elpersFactory->get('vendor/module/helperId')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83370/discussion-between-iqbal-malik-and-amit-bera).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

File path : /app/code/Namespace/ModuleName/Block/Html/CustomClassName
Use below code:

```
class CustomClassName{   

protected $_dataHelper;


public function __construct(       
    \Namespace\ModuleName\Helper\Data $dataHelper,
) {
    parent::__construct();        
    $this->_dataHelper = $dataHelper;
}

/**
 * @return mixed
 */
public function enableExtension()
{

    return $this->_dataHelper->enableExtension();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add your helper in the **__construct** function as given below.

```
<?php

class ClassName {

    protected $anotherHelper;

    public function __construct(
        \Vendor\Module\Helper\Data $anotherHelper
    ) {
        $this->anotherHelper = $anotherHelper;
    }

    public function callHelper(){

        $helperId = 'Other Module Helper';

        $dataHelper = $this->anotherHelper;

        return $dataHelper;
    }
}
```

Comment: If want to load helpers dynamically, than what we will do ?

Comment: What do you mean by loading the helper dynamically?

Comment: i update my question can you please see this.

Comment: Do you want to call multiple helpers in your phtml file?

Comment: No, actually when my shipping model execute, it call a class to decide which shipping method helper class need to execute.

Answer (score 0):

Use below code like as

```
    protected $helper;
    public function __construct(

            \Venor\Module\Helper\Data $helper,

        ) {

            $this->helper = $helper;
        }
   public function callHelper(){
    $dataHelper = $this->helper
    return $dataHelper;
   }
```